# Delete lines containing empty fields

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I want to delete the lines containing empty fields in the last row $7

File:

```
1 1479870 5022248660 1 40001 189445122 740020
1 1911574 3015889020 1 33001 162049034 633004
1 1569783 5029193930 1 22001 133687297 522216
1 2069616 1025856960 2 25001 185608704 
1 1741598 5021128160 1 44001 164870942 644027
1 1052941 5020319300 1 10001 156161802 610007
1 1686734 5020347480 1 13001 131405824 513304
1 1872263 5029089700 1 23001 185092353 723017
```

Desired output :

```
1 1479870 5022248660 1 40001 189445122 740020
1 1911574 3015889020 1 33001 162049034 633004
1 1569783 5029193930 1 22001 133687297 522216
1 1741598 5021128160 1 44001 164870942 644027
1 1052941 5020319300 1 10001 156161802 610007
1 1686734 5020347480 1 13001 131405824 513304
1 1872263 5029089700 1 23001 185092353 723017
```

Comment: `awk 'NF >= 7' <file`, note that it does not guarantee that the last field is empty, example the line were also deleted when one of other fields is empty.

Comment: How are your fields separated? Any amount of blank characters or one space character ? Is `1 2  4 5 6 7` (where there are two spaces in between 2 and 4) a line with a missing 3rd field or one with a missing 7th field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with this one :

```
awk  '$7!=""' file > final_output
```

Comment: @Nydenn If helped mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are separated by one space character as opposed to any sequence of blank characters, that if

```
1 2  4 5 6 7
```

Is a line that has a 7th field but no 3rd field, you'd do:

```
awk -F '[ ]' '$7 != ""' < file > final_output
```

`[ ]` is a regular expression that matches the space character. We don't use `-F ' '` as a single space as the field separator has a special meaning (gives the default field splitting behaviour where any sequence of one or more blank characters act as *one* separator and leading and trailing blanks are ignored).